# I have two mailto links in my email template and would like to have two different colors on it.(Blue & White)

Tags: html, css, email, html-email, email-templates

```
a[href^="mailto:"]

{ 

  color: blue;

}
```

I am using the above code and it's getting applied to both mailto links. Is there any way that we can have two different colors for mailto link? tried SPAN class but not working in Outlook.

Comment: pls share html and css...

Comment: share your HTML code...

Answer (score 1):

try like this

**HTML**

```
<body>
<a href="mailto:232322232" class="blue">232322232</a>
<a href="mailto:232322232" class="white">232322232</a>
</body>
```

**css**

```
body{
  background-color:#000;
}
a.blue{
  color:blue;
}
a.white{
  color:white;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The recommended way is to have the styles in-lined. This way you are sure that your link colours will work the same across every email clients.

**Note**: Some answers on this question are either using jquery or CSS in the head. jQuery doesn't work in emails and some email clients strip off `<head> ... </head>` from your document.

```html
<div style="background-color:#000000;padding:20px 10px;">

<a href="mailto:test@test.com">Send Mail 1</a>

<a href="mailto:test@test.com" style="color:#ffffff;text-decoration:underline;">Send Mail 2</a>

</div>
```

By default all links are blue. If you wish to change it to a different shade of blue you can use the code similar to the second link.

Comment: One more better way is to use images in anchor tag. Right?

Comment: @RK003 Not quiet. With images turned off in emails (like Outlook), users will not know what it is until they hover over the anchor. You can use HTML and CSS to make it boxed out.

Comment: The only answer.